# Diferenciar con qué parámetros se llamó a un método que tiene argumentos variables

Tags: java

Definí un método con argumentos variables:

```
public void ejemplo(String... nombres) {
    for (String unNombre : nombres) {
        System.out.println(unNombre);
    }
}
```

Y entonces lo puedo llamar de estas dos formas:

```
ejemplo("Ana", "Clara", "María");
ejemplo(new String[]{"Ana", "Clara", "María"});
```

Y me saltó la curiosidad: ¿Tengo forma de saber si se llamó al método con múltiples argumentos o con un array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, no hay forma de determinar de cual forma fue llamado. La razón es que cuando el compilador encuentra esta sentencia:

```
ejemplo("Ana", "Clara", "María");
```

... automáticamente la cambia a la segunda forma:

```
ejemplo(new String[]{"Ana", "Clara", "María"});
```

... de modo que al tiempo de ejecución, las llamadas son idénticas.

---

Referencia: [JLS - Sección 15.12.4.2. Evaluate Arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4):

> If `m` is being invoked with `k ≠ n` actual argument expressions, or, if `m` is being invoked with `k = n` actual argument expressions and the type of the `k`'th argument expression is not assignment compatible with `T[]`, then the argument list `(e1, ..., en-1, en, ..., ek)` is evaluated as if it were written as `(e1, ..., en-1, new |T[]| { en, ..., ek })`, where `|T[]|` denotes the erasure (§4.6) of `T[]`.

---

**Prueba adicional**

Si usas el siguiente programa minimalista:

```
public class VarargsTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ejemplo("Ana", "Clara", "María");
        ejemplo(new String[]{"Ana", "Clara", "María"});
    }

    private static void ejemplo(String... nombres) {
        for (String nombre : nombres) {
            System.out.println(nombre);
        }
    }
}
```

... y luego inspeccionas los byte codes generados por el compilador:

```
D:\java\JavaApplication1\build\classes>"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\javap" -c VarargsTest
Compiled from "VarargsTest.java"
public class VarargsTest {
  public VarargsTest();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: iconst_3
       1: anewarray     #2                  // class java/lang/String
       4: dup
       5: iconst_0
       6: ldc           #3                  // String Ana
       8: aastore
       9: dup
      10: iconst_1
      11: ldc           #4                  // String Clara
      13: aastore
      14: dup
      15: iconst_2
      16: ldc           #5                  // String Marφa
      18: aastore
      19: invokestatic  #6                  // Method ejemplo:([Ljava/lang/String;)V
      22: iconst_3
      23: anewarray     #2                  // class java/lang/String
      26: dup
      27: iconst_0
      28: ldc           #3                  // String Ana
      30: aastore
      31: dup
      32: iconst_1
      33: ldc           #4                  // String Clara
      35: aastore
      36: dup
      37: iconst_2
      38: ldc           #5                  // String Marφa
      40: aastore
      41: invokestatic  #6                  // Method ejemplo:([Ljava/lang/String;)V
      44: return
}
```

Notarás que la sentencia `ejemplo("Ana", "Clara", "María");` corresponde a las líneas 0 a 19.

Y la sentencia `ejemplo(new String[]{"Ana", "Clara", "María"});` corresponde a las líneas 22 a 41.

Si los comparas, verás que no hay ninguna diferencia.

Comment: Claro. Siempre es bueno esperar. Aproveché para agregar una información adicional que me pareció interesante.

Comment: Excelentemente documentado. Y queda claro que en `1: anewarray` (*"a new array"*) está generando el nuevo array.